# Import csv to impala

Tags: sql, impala

So for my previous homework, we were asked to import a csv file with no columns names to impala, where we explicitly give the name and type of each column while creating the table. However, now we have a csv file but with column names given, in this case, do we still need to write down the name and type of it even it is provided in the data?

Comment: yes..you still have to create the table with appropriate column data types and skip the first line in the csv when loading it to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you still have to create an external table and define the column names and types. But you have to pass the following option right at the end of the create table statement

```
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");

-- Once the table property is set, queries skip the specified number of lines
-- at the beginning of each text data file. Therefore, all the files in the table
-- should follow the same convention for header lines.
```